# Copying diff results files

Tags: linux, directory, filenames, cp

I have two folders - Folder A and Folder B.

I compared the files from both folders using diff command. Now after finding that certain files are only available in Folder A and Certain files in Folder B, I would like copy those distinctive files from both folders into 1 folder called folder C which will now have all the unique files from both A and B

How can I do this?

Comment: files are distinct because of their filenames, I assume?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: Is there a penalty to copying files that exist in both places?  The simplest way is `mkdir folderC; cp -p folderA/* folderB/* folderC/`. If there is a penalty, then `rsync` is easy: `mkdir folderC; rsync -av folderA/ folderC; rsync -av folderB/ folderC/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [zsh's array subtraction and brace expansion features](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html), like so:

Setup:

```
$ tree .
.
├── folderA
│   ├── file0
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── folderB
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   └── file4
└── folderC

3 directories, 6 files


cd folderA
A=(*)
cd ../folderB
B=(*)
cd ..
```

Execution:

```
cp folderA/${^A:|B} folderB/${^B:|A} folderC
```

Result:

```
$ tree folderC
folderC
├── file0
├── file1
├── file3
└── file4

0 directories, 4 files
```

The two setup steps create arrays (named `A` and `B`) that contain the filenames in folders A and B, respectively.

The execution step asks `cp` to copy the expansion of the `A` array minus the `B` array, all prefixed with `folderA` as well as the corresponding expansion of the `B` array minus the `A` array (all prefixed with `folderB`) into `folderC`.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution using `diff`, `sed` and `xargs`:

Test setup:

```
$ mkdir folderA folderB folderC
$ touch folderA/fi\ le1 folderA/file2 folderA/file3 folderB/file3 folderB/file4
$ diff -rq folderA folderB
Only in folderA: fi le1
Only in folderA: file2
Only in folderB: file4
```

Now we use `sed` to filter all lines starting with string `Only in folderA:` and we change this part to `folderA/` to form a 
relative filename with quotes (`'folderA/fi le1'`). This string is then piped to `xargs` and used to copy this file to `folderC`.

```
$ diff -rq folderA folderB | sed -n "s/^Only in \(folderA\): \(.*\)/'\1\/\2'/p" | xargs cp -vt folderC
'folderA/fi le1' -> 'folderC/fi le1'
'folderA/file2' -> 'folderC/file2'
```

The same as above for `folderB`:

```
$ diff -rq folderA folderB | sed -n "s/^Only in \(folderB\): \(.*\)/'\1\/\2'/p" | xargs cp -vt folderC
'folderB/file4' -> 'folderC/file4'
```